# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' in Python 3.8+

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following folder layout:

[image]

The files have the following contents:

**library.py**

```
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y
```

**test.py**

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent))


from src.code.library import add


print(add("as", 2))
```

Now, when I run the following command from inside `test/`:

- `python test.py`

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    from src.code.library import add
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Can someone please help me out? I am using Python 3.8 so apparently do not need the `__init__.py` files that a lot of the answers I looked at previously.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. I read the canonical answer here:

[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

But did not really understand how it works for Python 3.8. The type error in the code is intentional.

Comment: you definitely need the `__init__.py` files (to create packages) and you don't need to use `sys.path` (or at least `__init__.py` files make is so much easier)

Comment: Thanks @Matiiss, would you know how I could solve my problem? I used added an init file in my `src` directory but it has not helped.

Comment: `code` directory also should be a package and so should be `test` or at least so I understand